# SQL: Query to order colums to rows based on type

Tags: sql, row, mac-address, sccm

I've been working on a report based on SCCM data. ;-)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ResourceID
            ,   AdapterType0
            ,   MACAddress0

FROM    V_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER 

WHERE   MACAddress0 is not null
```

I get a result like this:

| ResourceID | AdapterType0 | MACAddress0 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 16777255 | Ethernet 802.3 | 00:00:00:00:00:00 |
| 16777255 | Ethernet 802.3 | 11:11:11:11:11:11 |
| 16777255 | Wide Area Network (WAN) | 33:33:33:33:33:33 |

But I would like to turn it around and get a result like

| ResourceID | AdapterType0 | AdapterType1 | AdapterType2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16777255 | Ethernet 802.3: 00:00:00:00:00:00; 11:11:11:11:11:11 | Wide Area Network (WAN): 33:33:33:33:33:33 | NULL |

I've tried with STUFF, but can't quite get the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT  ResourceID,AdapterType0,AdapterType1,AdapterType2

FROM    V_GS_NETWORK_ADAPTER
WHERE ResourceID='16777255'and AdapterType2 is NULL

Comment: Yes that would be easy if data was organized like that, but it is not. It is organized as shown in the first table.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).